# Incorrrect Output

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am using Dev C++ Compiler. I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
        ~Test();
};
Test::Test()
{
        cout << "Constructor is executed\n";
}
Test::~Test()
{
        cout << "Destructor is executed\n";
}
int main()
{
        new Test();
        return 0;
}
```

Output

```
    Constructor is executed
```

In this code why is Destructor not been invoked automatically.

But when I try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
        ~Test();
};
Test::Test()
{
        cout << "Constructor is executed\n";
}
Test::~Test()
{
        cout << "Destructor is executed\n";
}
int main()
{
        delete new Test();
        return 0;
}
```

Output

```
    Constructor is executed
    Destructor is executed
```

What is the reason for the difference in these outputs ?

Comment: Its `C++` not `java`. In `C++` you have to manage memory yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because **delete** calls the destructor of the object you just have created with new.

so in this case, no delete = no destructor call.

Looks like you are new to C++ so for your info both objects are created on the heap. (use this for future research).

Answer (score 2):

Objects dynamically created by `new` are never destroyed automatically; they are only destroyed by `delete`. Your first example doesn't do that (so the object is leaked), and your second example does.

If you want it to be destroyed automatically, then give it automatic storage duration:

```
int main()
{
    Test t;       // Created here, on declaration
    return 0;     // Destroyed here, when it goes out of scope
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is like you pee() and then as soon as Infrared Automatic Toilet Urinal Sensor detects that you are done, it flushes your pee.

```
{
   pee p;
}
```

but Infrared Automatic Toilet Urinal Sensors are not installed everywhere, so you must press the knob so that it flushes your pee.

```
{ 
  pee *p = new pee();
  delete p;
}
```

have you got the difference now?

Comment: Exactly my type of humour! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have created object on heap. That means you have to explicitly call `delete` on that object to de-allocate memory occupied by that object.